# how to show table data regarding to id in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing project management app using Laravel. In my application I have a project and one project have many tasks and one task have many comments.

So, I have **comment table** like as below.

```
id    comment            project_id            user_id
1         abc               1                    1
2        dcf                1                    2
3        fgt                2                    1
4        fgt                2                    2
5        fhgt               1                    3
```

**Comment controller** for comment post is as below.

```
public function postNewComment(Request $request, $id, Comment $comment)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comments' => 'required|min:5',
    ]);

    $comment->comments   = $request->input('comments');
    $comment->project_id = $id;
    $comment->user_id    = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Comment posted successfully');
}
```

and this is my **Comment model** is as below.

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['comments', 'project_id', 'user_id'];

        public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }



     public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
    }

}
```

In my application user can visit their project area using `projectController` `index` function

```
public function index()
     {
        $projects = Project::all();
        return view('projects.index')->withProjects($projects);
}
```

and then when click on one project link user can see tasks created form and existing tasks list for relevant project. my task created form is in projects folder in view file in resources folder and existing task list include with this file `projects/show.blade.php`.

```
 @include('tasks.index')
```

`tasks/index.blade.php` file is

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
    <h4><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a></h4>
@endforeach
```

my project model is

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['project_name','project_notes','project_status','color','group'];
    //

    public function tasks(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}

public function comments()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}


}
```

now when I click one of existing task link I can see comment box and now I need show comment table comment on each task related with each project. I mean I need 
to show each project comments on every tasks witch is related to that project.

can you give me some help?

Thanks!